# Adding an inner join makes query show duplicates

Tags: mysql, sql

shows a subset of the tables

```
SELECT cont.ID, cont.UUID
FROM  `contract` cont
INNER JOIN geoPoint geo ON geo.cUUID = cont.c_UUID
WHERE geo.geotype =1
AND geo.g_UUID =  '$uuid'
```

adding an additional gt

```
  SELECT cont.ID, cont.UUID
    FROM  `contract` cont
    INNER JOIN geoPoint geo ON geo.cUUID = cont.c_UUID
    INNER JOIN tier gt ON gt.UUID = cont.price_tier
    WHERE geo.geotype =1
    AND geo.g_UUID =  '$uuid' AND gt.type = 0
```

now it shows thousands of repeated items

Comment: This looks a bit iffy "gt.UUID = cont.price_tier"

Comment: Just seems weird from a design standpoint, where you seem to have most such fields suffixed with UUID, to come across that. You should probably add the table definitions.

Comment: any suggestions to my problem?

Comment: Use `DISTINCT`. `SELECT DISTINCT cont.ID ...`

Comment: sample data and expected results (ideally in sqlfiddle) will help

Comment: @Bulat not sure how to do that I have thousands of lines
I am expecting to see only one contract that matches the following items - yet I see multiple contracts

Comment: what happens when you select other columns from your tables? see if you still get duplicates?

Comment: @morty346 that is why you need to provide sample of data that will be enough to explain your requirements (no need in thousands of examples to explain functional requirements)

Answer (score 0):

It is highly likely you will need to better explain what you are looking for and how your data relates for you to get a non-guessing answer, but here is my wild guess...

```
SELECT cont.ID, cont.UUID
FROM  `contract` cont
WHERE cont.c_UUID IN (
    SELECT geo.cUUID 
    FROM geoPoint AS geo 
    WHERE geo.geotype =1
    AND geo.g_UUID =  '$uuid'
)
AND cont.price_tier IN (
    SELECT gt.UUID 
    FROM tier AS gt
    WHERE gt.type = 0 
)
;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `EXISTS` clause if you tier table has multiple values per UUID (which is strange)

```
SELECT cont.ID, cont.UUID
FROM  `contract` cont
INNER JOIN geoPoint geo ON geo.cUUID = cont.c_UUID
WHERE geo.geotype =1
AND geo.g_UUID =  '$uuid' AND gt.type = 0
AND EXISTS (SELECT * FROM tier gt WHERE gt.UUID = cont.price_tier)
```

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to troubleshoot a `JOIN` that is returning more records than anticipated is to look at the data to see what's causing it.  Taking `DISTINCT *` from one table at a time will show you the cause, in this case it seems obvious that it's the `tier` table since that's the addition that caused trouble:

```
  SELECT DISTINCT gt.*
    FROM  `contract` cont
    INNER JOIN geoPoint geo ON geo.cUUID = cont.c_UUID
    INNER JOIN tier gt ON gt.UUID = cont.price_tier
    WHERE geo.geotype =1
    AND geo.g_UUID =  '$uuid' AND gt.type = 0
```

Observe the values for `gt.UUID` that have multiple rows, then you'll be able to determine the best course of action... perhaps there are blank values joining to many records on each side, perhaps there's another field you need to add to your `JOIN` criteria... regardless, observing the data will help you determine what's wrong, because as you said, your query looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT  cont.ID, cont.UUID

FROM  `contract` cont

INNER JOIN geoPoint geo ON geo.cUUID = cont.c_UUID

INNER JOIN tier gt ON gt.UUID = cont.price_tier

WHERE geo.geotype =1

AND geo.g_UUID =  '$uuid' AND gt.type = 0
```